# Computing $\int_\mathbb{R} P \left( Y_2 \mid Y_1, X \right) \mathrm{d} y_2$.

Tags: probability

I want to find
$$\int_\mathbb{R} P \left( Y_2 = y_2 \mid Y_1 = y_1, X = x \right) \mathrm{d} y_2$$

It seems intuitive that the result would be 1, but the conditional probability is making me unsure. Is 1 correct, and if so, is there an easy example to show it is the case? Or is it impossible to simplify this in the current form?

Comment: Do you mean to use a conditional PDF instead of a conditional probability?  The integral you give could easily be zero, for example, if $Y_2$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ and independent of $(Y_1, X)$.

Comment: I am confused by your example. If $Y_2$ is independent of $Y_1$ and $X$, then wouldn't $P \left( Y_2 = y_2 \mid Y_1 = y_1, X = x \right) = P \left( Y_2 \right)$ and therefore the integral would have to be 1 per the second [Kolmogorov axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axiom)?

Comment: There is no such thing as $P[Y_2]$.  Are you making up your own notation?  You can only take probabilities of _events_, not random variables. "The probability that $Y_2$ is less than 4" makes sense, but "The probaiblity that $Y_2$" does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, my bad, typo. I meant here $P \left( Y_2 = y_2 \right)$, and so yes $P$ is a probability density.

Comment: You can use the conditional density definition $f_{Y_2|(Y_1, X)}(y_2|y_1, x) = \frac{f_{Y_2, Y_1, X}(y_2, y_1, x)}{f_{Y_1,X}(y_1,x)}$ and integrate out $y_2$.

Comment: Your notation is confusing. If $P$ is a *density* the integral is 1 (aside from fringe cases in which the joint density of $Y_1, X$ is zero for the indicated values). You should assume that $Y_1 = y_1$ and $X = x$ are a given and so your integral just says how much is the probability for $Y_2$ to be any real value, and this is of course 1.